# How do I obtain credentials from the Cognito Identity pool using Kotlin SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-cognito

I setup a user pool in Amazon Cognito, and an accompanying identity pool. I can successfully authenticate my username/password against the user pool. As a next step, I wish to exchange the token I received for a Cognito Identity and thus obtain temporary credentials to access AWS services. I am using the Kotlin SDK in an Android app, and I'm having a hard time finding any code examples, as well as relevant API documentation.

So far I have the following in my login method:

```kotlin
    fun login(emailVal: String, passwordVal: String) {
        val userPoolClient = CognitoIdentityProviderClient() { region = "eu-north-1" }
        val identityPoolClient = CognitoIdentityClient() { region = "eu-north-1" }

        val authParas = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
        authParas["USERNAME"] = emailVal
        authParas["PASSWORD"] = passwordVal

        val loginRequest = InitiateAuthRequest {
            clientId = cognitoClientId
            authParameters = authParas
            authFlow = AuthFlowType.UserPasswordAuth
        }

        var idToken = ""
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            userPoolClient.use { identityProviderClient ->
                try {
                    val result = identityProviderClient.initiateAuth(loginRequest)
                    idToken = result.authenticationResult?.idToken ?: ""
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    _loginState.value = BooleanMessage(message = e.message.toString(), success = false)
                }
            }
            
            //...And now what?
        }

    }
```

What is the next step? The authenticationResult value has both accessToken and idToken. Is the idToken from the Cognito Identity pool? Did the API take care of this for me? If not, then what?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know, but you might mixing up Cognito and and general AWS service access.  If you want to access AWS services, this is dealt with easily using `AwsCredentialsProvider`.  My experience of Cognito is that we are using pretty much the code you posted to generate an OAuth access (& refresh) token.  We then use that to authenticate against AWS' API Gateway which protects our bespoke REST API endpoints.

Comment: @AndrewL I'm not mixing up two different things. This is the Amazon recommended flow for connecting mobile devices to IOT Core devices: use Cognito user pool for authentication, and then exchange the id token for a temporary Cognito Identity from the identity pool, and then attach a policy to the identity. Anyway, I posted my own answer if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```kotlin
val loginSettings: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
loginSettings["cognito-idp.<REGION>.amazonaws.com/<USER_POOL_ID>"] = idToken
val identityRequest = GetIdRequest {
    identityPoolId = "<REGION>:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    logins = loginSettings
}
var result: GetIdResponse
try {
    result = identityPoolClient.getId(identityRequest)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    _loginState.value = BooleanMessage(message = e.message.toString(), success = false)
}
```

Comment: Good work @Primordial_Hamster